# set args for JDB

Tags: java, jdb

The command I use to execute my Java code is:

```
java -cp /usr/local/share/java/dbus.jar:/usr/local/share/java/unix.jar:/usr/local/share/java/debug-disable.jar:. \
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/jniCaller3 org.freedesktop.DBus" "/org/freedesktop/DBus" "org.freedesktop.DBus" "Hello"
```

How can I pass the args into JDB?

```
~/jdbus> jdb Caller3
Initializing jdb ...
>
```

Now what? With GDB I'd simply use ***set args***.

```
> set args -cp /usr/local/share/java/dbus.jar:/usr/local/share/java/unix.jar:/usr/local/share/java/debug-disable.jar:. \
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/jni org.freedesktop.DBus" "/org/freedesktop/DBus" "org.freedesktop.DBus" "Hello"
```

Comment: You comman looks broken, because it does not contain a `Caller3`. Which is you main class in the command you call manually? `To the closing double quote at the end of this part `.../jniCaller3 org.freedesktop.DBus"` there is not opening one.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2095 You can start you Java application and then, simply connect to it using jdb.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass arguments into jdb

```
> cat Code.java
public class Code {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    System.out.println(arg[0]);
  }
}
> javac Code.java
> java -cp . Code Hello
Hello
> jdb -classpath . Code hello
Initializing jdb ...
> run
run Code hello
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: hello

The application exited
```